# MVVM Light RaisePropertyChanged dosen't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

With this in Model:

```
 namespace PlanszaGlowna.Model
 {
     public class PlanszaGlowna
     {
         public bool CzyWidoczny { get; set; }
```

With this in ViewModel

```
namespace PlanszaGlowna.WidokModelu
{
    public class PlanszaGlowna : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Model.PlanszaGlowna m_PlanszaGlowna;

        public bool CzyWidoczny
        {
            get { return m_PlanszaGlowna.CzyWidoczny; }
            set
            {
                m_PlanszaGlowna.CzyWidoczny = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => CzyWidoczny);
            }
        }
```

And that binding:

```
         <UserControl x:Class="PlanszaGlowna.Widok.PlanszaGlowna" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         Visibility="{Binding Path=CzyWidoczny, Converter={StaticResource Bool2VisibilityKonwerter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

UI doesn't update when I set a new value for CzyWidoczny in ViewModel. I'm using MVVM Light.

Comment: I might be missing something due to the non-English property names, but where do you set the data context?

Comment: @user3714853 how and where do you set `DataContext`? Does changing the initial value have some effect?

Comment: I set data context in parent view:

<PlanszaGlowna:PlanszaGlowna DataContext="{Binding PlanszaGlowna}"/>

In first set CzyWidoczny property, View get the value but in another set they don't.

Comment: shot in the dark but in your `PlanszaGlowna.Widok.PlanszaGlowna` `UserControl` do you do something like `DataContext = this;` or set it in any other way?

Comment: I think DataContext is Ok because other properties displaying correctly. When I change the CzyWidoczny property in ViewModel he enter the setter and change the property in model but after RaisePropertyChanged they don't enter to getter.

Comment: `CzyWidoczny` property looks fine. In that case do you set manually `Visibility` of `PlanszaGlowna.Widok.PlanszaGlowna` somewhere in code?

Comment: I recommend you use snoopwpf.codeplex.com to view your bindings/datacontext/etc during runtime to make sure something isn't breaking the binding.

Comment: I beg you, don't name variables in Polish...

Answer (score 0):

issue is the model class PlanszaGlowna.Model.PlanszaGlowna does not implement INotifiyPropertyChanged

so implement the same and change to

```
 public class PlanszaGlowna : INotifiyPropertyChanged
 {
    ...
    private _CzyWidoczny;
    public bool CzyWidoczny
    {
        get { return _CzyWidoczny; }
        set
        {
            _CzyWidoczny = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CzyWidoczny");
        }
    }
```

this will work as long as your class PlanszaGlowna.Model.PlanszaGlowna implements INotifiyPropertyChanged and you have created the wrapper method RaisePropertyChanged to invoke the PropertyChanged event

Answer (score 0):

If you try in your binding some like this:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="PlanszaGlowna.Widok.PlanszaGlowna" 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     Visibility="{Binding Path=CzyWidoczny, Converter={StaticResource Bool2VisibilityKonwerter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to bind. Also revise your property has been created with next structure:

```
private string _text= "";
public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text= value; RaisePropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }
```

On in case Text property belong a class, it has next structure:

```
public class NewClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if ( _text!= value)
            {
                _text= value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```